# Añadir diseño de Bootstrap en un tag Django

Tags: css, bootstrap, django

Necesito añadir una clase de Bootstrap a un tag de Django

```
{{ form.new_password1 }}
```

Pero realmente no se como se podría realizar.

Answer (score 0):

Se puede añadir la clase directamente en el form

```
from django import forms
from apps.Modelo import Modelo

class ModeloForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Modelo


        fields = [
            'tipo',
        ]

        labels = {

            'tipo': 'Tipo',
        }

        widgets = {

            'tipo': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'select'}),
           #'nombre': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'input-field'}),
        }
```

En el caso anterior puse como clase un select, como es un 'Tipo' para que se despliegue una lista con opciones, pero puedes poner un 'input-field' (como lo dejé en el comentario de nombre) o lo que sea como clase